# Video on OSX in Firefox won't play from website?

Tags: html, macos, video, mp4, webm

I'm encountering an issue where: mp4, .webM and .ogg are not working in Firefox, specificly on Mac's OSX.. and only in Firefox, when viewing my page on a Windows Computer wth Firefox, it however works perfectly..

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

This website says Firefox supports all three: mp4, webM and ogg.. may I ask why it doesn't place specificaly on Mac's OSX?

fixed - slight spelling mistake was the issue

HTML:

```
<video preload="auto" type="video/mp4" height="500" width="880" id="video">
    <source src="fragmenten/binnenkomst.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="fragmenten/binnenkomst.webm" type="video/webm"> </source>


  Your browser does not support the video element.
</video>
```

However, when I drag the video in the browser it does work? It just won't play from my website?